# Rails add_foreign_key limited to a single reference field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I am working with a database that uses a lot of constraints defined within the schema. This is necessary, to ensure that other services and clients that use the database do not break the data model (please don't reply that this level of DB definition is inappropriate for a Rails application). Unfortunately this seems to take Rails beyond its ability to define, dump and subsequently recreate schemas, unless somebody knows something that I have missed.

The specific issue that I have encountered is with `add_foreign_key` statements in *schema.rb*, and I am looking to see if anybody knows a workaround that will save me embedding SQL directly into the *schema.rb* definition.

The Postgres DDL that I need to represent is:

```
ALTER TABLE ONLY trackers
  ADD CONSTRAINT valid_protocol_sub_process 
  FOREIGN KEY (protocol_id, sub_process_id) 
  REFERENCES sub_processes(protocol_id, id) MATCH FULL;
```

Unfortunately, when I `rake db:schema:dump` the existing database to *schema.rb* this results in the following:

```
add_foreign_key "trackers", "sub_processes", 
  column: "protocol_id", 
  primary_key: "protocol_id", 
  name: "valid_protocol_sub_process"
```

This results in an invalid specification, when recreating the database, that only includes a single field and (fortunately) fails to run, since the resulting schema constraints would be incorrect.

I have attempted to change the **primary_key** and **column** option strings to include both fields to match the required SQL, but ActiveRecord puts quotes around the whole lot, making the SQL statement invalid. I also attempted to use an array of columns too, but it appears to just `#to_s` the array.

Is this just beyond the ability of `add_foreign_key`, or is there a way to use multiple fields in a foreign key specification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that there is no checking that schema.rb can validly represent the full database if you use database specific DDL. Although I understand that schema.rb may not be able to represent every possibility, it is unfortunately that there is no error produced to indicate that the schema.rb generated by rake is invalid.

In order to get a full SQL dump of the database, performed by the database's own schema dumping tool, I added:

```
config.active_record.schema_format = :sql
```

to application.rb. This ensures that in future I get a valid, usable database schema to rebuild an environment.